# What are excavated/relic weapons?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

"Excavated", also known as "Relic", weapons are a new feature in Monster Hunter 4(U).

What are they and how do you get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excavated weapons are weapons found in Everwood expeditions. These weapons start off with another weapon as a base, but come with randomized stats.

You could conceivably find an Excavated weapon with *much* higher stats (or lower) than its base. They also have some slight visual differences, but it's easy to see which weapon they take as their base.